# Possible ways of installing Magento other than localhost server

Tags: magento2, php, zend-framework, slowbackend

Currently I have tried Magento with XAMPP localhost. **Eventually I'm experiencing a terrible slowness in loading up Magento.** Hope anyone could help me out in finding a proper solution other than the localhost server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either you can run magento into docker using virtual drive( but i have problem with that share data between that) or you can use AWS server, it is free for one year.

Hope it will help you.